# timer, refresher

Tags: java, android, timer

how do i develop an app that draws a line on screen at fixed coordinates, Setting up a repeating timer of 1 second duration? On every tick of the timer,the line refreshes.

LineRefresh.java:

```
package LineRefresh.xyz.com;

import java.util.Timer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LineRefresh extends Activity {
DrawView drawView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

drawView = new DrawView(this);
drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
setContentView(drawView);
}
}

DrawView.java:

 package LineRefresh.xyz.com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawView(Context context) {
super(context);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawLine(50, 200, 270, 200, paint);
}  

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'refreshs'? Do the coordinates change?

Comment: no...its only redraws the line once it refreshes in the same co-ordinates

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and use it's `postDelayed()` to schedule drawing a line.

After you draw a line also schedule another `postDelayed()` to continue this process.

Comment: i have provided my code...can you please tell me how to use the handler class in it?